# Using KVO to track a change in count of NSArray

Tags: ios

My app uses multi peer connectivity to send files to other devices in IOS7. With this framework more than one device can connect to the MCSession, and there is a specific array that gives us the count of the number of devices connected. I want to be notified when there is a change to this count, but I don't seem to understand how to make the array KVO compliant, even if I so numerous internet links and questions. The problem is that this array is controlled externally:

```
[session connectedPeers];
```

To get the count I do:

```
NSArray* array = [session connectedPeers];
array.count
```

But it is not the array which changes, rather the [session connectedPeers];

How can I track this change?

Comment: Does `MCSessionDelegate` not offer what you want?

Comment: I don't think so... but it might be. I haven't seen anything about it in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MCSessionDelegate` provides the `session:peer:didChangeState:` method which should notify you when any peer connects or disconnects from the session.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: ([NSArray Class reference])[1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:/)

> **addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:**
>
> NSArray objects are not observable, so this method raises an exception
> when invoked on an NSArray object. Instead of observing an array,
> observe the to-many relationship for which the array is the collection
> of related objects.

I'd suggest using a MCSessionDelegate method as mentioned by Wain.